# Delete image saved using private mode

Tags: android, image, android-bitmap

I'm saving a Bitmap in order to send the file name to another activity. This is the code I'm using to do this:

```
@Nullable
public static String saveImage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, int pos, String TAG)
{
    String fileName = "thumbnail_" + pos + ".png";

    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fileOutStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutStream.write(byteArray);

        fileOutStream.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error guardando la imagen");

        return null;
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

What I want to do is when exiting the activity, delete this image. How can I know where this image has been saved and how can I delete it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileName` is the path to your file in your app internal storage and your `Context` has a method called `deleteFile(String name)` where `name` is your `fileName`.

So, just call `context.deleteFile(fileName)`.

You can check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile(java.lang.String)).